# How to send message followed by start to a bot by link using telethon?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telethon

I want to interact with a bot which takes chat id and message id and replies based on the message of that chat id.

Usually I interact with the bot in a group chat using `KeyboardButtonUrl` having link (e.g. here is that url behind KeyboardButtonUrl, `https://t.me/SomeBot?start=-1001234567890_654321`) to the bot with data. I click on the button which directly opens the chat with bot & clicking on Start button, sends the command to the bot (I think bot fetches the message from the passed data having chat id and message id) .

Sending message '-1001234567890_654321' using `send_message` function doesn't work as expected.
How can I achieve this using telethon ?

Also After searching in [telethon docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/index.html), I could not find any function which returns a particular message after taking message id and chat id. `get_messages` & `iter_messages` returns specified no. of last msgs only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @oleskii's approach, but you can also just send a message like so:

```py
client.send_message('bot username', '/start params_string')
```

Comment: how can we get the bot reply after sending the message successfully? Any preferred approach for that?

Comment: Use `telethon.events`.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you want to start a bot with parameters.

Please refer to the following:
https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/start_bot.html

You can make it work tunning this example to your needs:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import StartBotRequest

request = StartBotRequest("bot_username_bot", "bot_username_bot", "params_string")
result = await client(request)
```

The request will work the same way like the following link would work:

https://t.me/bot_username_bot?start=params_string

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Comment: I tried your command. It ran successfully. But how can I get the bot reply ?

Comment: @jonny789 Were you able to get bot reply? If yes, how did you do it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I could not find any function which returns a particular message after taking message id and chat id

client `get_messages` method gives an `ids` argument that specify message id or list of ids.

```py
message = await client.get_messages(chat_id, ids=message_id)
```

return message object if given id exists or return `None`

---

```py
ids = [message_id_1, message_id_2, message_id_3, ...]

messages = await client.get_messages(chat_id, ids=ids)
```

return [total list](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/helpers.html#telethon.helpers.TotalList) of message objects with given id list. list item will be `None` if id does not exists.

[see the get_messages documentation here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.get_messages)